# Delete rows from a parent table without affecting the condition table

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, sql-delete

I have a main table and a secondary one. Through a query I connect the secondary with the primary on the left, to filter the results of the primary. PhpMyAdmin disables editing and deleting the results because it does not have a unique column.

```
SELECT 
main_table.Id,
main_table.CustomerId,
main_table.CustomerName,
main_table.CustomerMail,
main_table.TravelId,
secondary_table.Sell
FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN secondary_table ON secondary_table.TravelId = main_table.TravelId
WHERE main_table.TravelId < '2000'
AND secondary_table.Sell = '0'  
ORDER BY main_table.Id DESC;
```

I thought about using a delete query but I'm worried that it will affect the rows in the secondary table since I only want to delete the corresponding ones in the main table without affecting the secondary.

I would like to now:

1. How to fix the query or what I am doing wrong to make PhpMyAdmin throw that error, so I can delete the records manually from PhpMyAdmin.
2. On the other hand, to learn, I would like to know how I should perform a delete query so as not to delete any records from the secondary table, only from the main one but taking into account the filtering I do when connecting them and filtering by sell = '0' and TravelId < '2000'.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a cascading delete on the foreign key, but you don't want that.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to confirm that error.

Which rows do you want to delete?  Which table do you want to delete them from?  Is the `SELECT` that you provided fetching the rows you want to delete?  I doubt it, since it fetches data from both tables.

It seems like you don't need `LEFT`.

*Maybe* this is what you want:

```
DELETE
    FROM  main_table
    JOIN  secondary_table  ON secondary_table.TravelId = main_table.TravelId
    WHERE  main_table.TravelId <  '2000'
      AND  secondary_table.Sell = '0'
```

But read about multi-table DELETE in the manual.

Comment: Don't we need to list table names/alias in the DELETE clause to specify which one(s) to delete?

Comment: Hi @rick-james and thanks for your time. With that code I got this error: `code` #1064 - There is an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your version of the MariaDB server to find out the correct syntax to use near 'secondary_table ON secondary_table.TravelId = main_table.TravelId' on line 3  `code`